# Recibir datos select multiple serialize(); Jquery- Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Siempre el siguiente código para enviar y recibir datos de un formulario, primero los agrupo en formData y luego en php los saco uno por uno para saber su valor, sin embargo tengo unos selects múltiples y solo me toma el último valor ( o sea el último elemento seleccionado), alguien sabe como puedo saber todos los valores en el php?

Jquery:

```
function savepar(idForm){
    var formData = $("#"+idForm).serialize();
    $.ajax({
                data: { data:formData },
                type: "POST",
                url: "include/q_setData.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
             });
    return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
  parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
                foreach($searcharray as $nombre_campo => $valor){ 
                   $asignacion = "\$" . $nombre_campo . "='" . $valor . "';"; 
                       eval($asignacion);
                     echo $asignacion."  "."<br>";
                }
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el HTML del select?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Andress Blend ,

Cuando envias un campo select multiple usando serialize , el resultado de la url codificada es parecido a este

```
lista=1&lista=2&lista=3
```

Siendo el html el siguiente

```
<select name="lista" multiple> 
    <option selected value="1">1</option>
    <option selected  value="2">2</option>
    <option selected  value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Debería enviar algo parecido a esto, o al menos es lo que nos gustaría que apareciera.

```
lista=[1,2,3]&otraVariable=valor
```

Para poder conseguirlo prueba a usar JSON.Stringify de esta manera

```
<?php
  if($_POST)
   echo var_dump($_POST);
  else{
?>
<form id="formulario" action="javascript:savepar('formulario')">
   <select name="lista" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div> 
<script >
function savepar(idForm) {
    var formData = $("#" + idForm).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data)
        }
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
<?php }?>
```

Como podrás ver ya lo tendrás en una lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la información adicional de las herramientas de desarrollador puedes ver la diferencia de como se envia con stringify y sin stringify.

Con stringify

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin Stringify

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir realmente si que lo envía , pero con el mismo nombre y php vuelve a setear la variable.

Un saludo y espero que te haya solventado la duda.